# Ends-with and Starts-with in if statements: Python 3

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, startswith, ends-with

I am new to python and I have to create a program that validates a DNA sequence.
(background on DNA sequences really quick)
in order to be valid:
•   The number of characters is divisible by 3
•   The first 3 characters are ATG
•   The last 3 characters are TAA, TAG, or TGA.

my problem comes in with using Boolean terms in an if statement.

```
        endswith=(DNA.endswith("TAA"))
endswith2=(DNA.endswith("TAG"))
endswith3=(DNA.endswith("TGA"))
if length%3==0 and startswith==true and endswith==true or endswith2==true or endswith3==true:
    return ("true")
```

this code returns the error of: 
global name 'true' is not defined

How do I fix this, and also just on a last note I am really sorry.
The answer to this question is probably SO stupidly simple that in your mind a 2 year old could code it :/  I did research around but I had no luck at all.  So I thank you for taking your time to even read my stupid question.

Answer (score 5):

Much easier:

```
return (len(DNA) % 3 == 0 and
        DNA.startswith("ATG") and
        DNA.endswith(("TAA", "TAG", "TGA")))
```

Comparing a boolean value to `True` or `False` is almost always redundant, so whenever you find yourself doing that ... do something else ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In python, `true` is not a keyword but `True`.

And in python you don't have to compare a variable with `True` obviously, just use

```
if length%3==0 and startswith and endswith or endswith2 or endswith3:
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing: it's `True` not `true`.

Second thing: don't say `endswith == True`, just say `endswith`.

Third thing: `and` has higher precedence than `or`, so what you've written is equivalent to:

```
(length%3==0 and startswith==true and endswith==true) or ...
```

which isn't what you meant.

Fourth thing: it's probably better to say:

```
if len(DNA) % 3 == 0 and DNA.startswith('ATG') and DNA[-3:] in ('TAA', 'TAG', 'TGA'):
```

As Tim points out, `DNA.endswith(('TAA', 'TAG', 'TGA'))` beats `DNA[-3:] in ...`. It's simpler and without bothering to test, I'd expect it to be faster too. If you had a lot of permissible endings of equal length, and you were doing many tests, then it would be faster to construct a  `set` once and do an `in` test of the end-slice. But three possibilities is not "a lot".

Comment: Note that `.endswith()` accepts a tuple of strings to try - no need for explicit slicing here.

Comment: Fair point, will change it. I think I knew that although for some reason it never occurs to me to use it.

Comment: Well, if you change it, your answer will be identical to mine ;-)

Comment: My answer has *many* things, only one of them would be identical to your answer! Of course the first three are made irrelevant by the fourth.

Comment: That's only because I didn't add your other 3 yet ;-)

Answer (score 0):

type: true --> True

you'd better refer to manual before you ask question.

Actually, you can use this:

```
if length%3 and startswith and endswith or ...
```

no need to write

```
if ... startswith == True ...
```

Comment: It is `length%3==0`, at least you should use `not (length%3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `True`, not `true`. Also, instead of `startswith==True`, you can just use `startswith` (eg: `if length%3==0 and startswith and endswith ...`).

You should also add parentheses to make your logic more readable. Even though precedence is well documented, many people don't know it. And even when they do, they can't tell if *you* do or not.

```
if (length%3==0 and (startswith and endswith) or endswith2 or endswith3):
```